# Django CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: django

I'm building this wiki post and I encountered an error when ever I try to save data.
I'm using django 1.4.3 at the moment and the tutorial i'm using is pretty old. So I don't think CSRF was included in the older version.

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
Help

Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token missing or incorrect
     In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

 Your browser is accepting cookies.
 The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
 In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that   targets an internal URL.
 If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
```

I think the problem is in my templates but I'll list my views.py anyway

My views are :

```
 from wiki.models import Page
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 def view_page(request,page_name):
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         return render_to_response("create.html",{"page_name":page_name})
     content = page.content
     return render_to_response("view.html",{"page_name":page_name , "content":content})
 def edit_page(request,page_name):
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
         content = page.content
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         content = ""
     return render_to_response("edit.html",{"page_name":page_name, "content":content})
 def save_page(request , page_name):
     content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk = page_name)
         page.content = content
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         page = Page(name= page_name , content=content)
         page.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name + "/")
```

My create.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>{{page.name}} - Create </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>{{page_name}} </h1>
    This page does not exist. <a href="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/edit/">Create?     </a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My edit.html , I added the {% csrf_token %} inside but seem to fail.

```
  <html>
<head>
    <title>{{page_name - Editing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Editing {{page_name}} </h1>
    <form method = "post" action="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/save/"> {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea name="content" rows="20" cols="60"> {{content}}
  </textarea><br/>      
        <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
        </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

My views.py template

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>{{page_name}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{page_name}} </h1>
    {{content}}
    <hr/>
    <a href="/wikicamp/{{page_name}}/edit/">Edit this page ?</a>
</body>
   </html>
```

My URLconf:

```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.conf import settings

  admin.autodiscover()
  urlpatterns = patterns('',

      url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
      url(r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/edit/$','wiki.views.edit_page'),
      url(r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/save/$','wiki.views.save_page'),
      url(r'^wikicamp/(?P<page_name>[^/]+)/$','wiki.views.view_page'),

  )
```

How could I fix this prooblem?

Comment: use context_instance=RequestContext(request)

Comment: Okay , could you expand on your answer. Pleaes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add context_instance=RequestContext(request) to every view that you will use a form inside it:
It seems you are not passing the context processor

```
 from wiki.models import Page
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 def view_page(request,page_name):
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         return render_to_response("create.html",{"page_name":page_name})
     content = page.content
     return render_to_response("view.html",{"page_name":page_name , "content":content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
 def edit_page(request,page_name):
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
         content = page.content
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         content = ""
     return render_to_response("edit.html",{"page_name":page_name, "content":content}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
 def save_page(request , page_name):
     content = request.POST.get('content', 'this is the default')
     try:
         page = Page.objects.get(pk = page_name)
         page.content = content
     except Page.DoesNotExist:
         page = Page(name= page_name , content=content)
         page.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name + "/")
```

Give a try to this .

Still you are getting the problem please post the urls .py also

Answer (score 2):

> `from django.template import RequestContext`
>
> `return render_to_response('contact_form.html',`
> `{'errors': errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

and also use the csrf_token tag inside the  element if the form is for an internal URL, e.g.:

```
 "form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}"
```

[reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/)